# AngularJS CKEditor img tags removed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in angularJS. I am trying to save notes using CKEditor  which can include images. It works fine for all other HTML tags but some how `<img>` tags are filtered when tried to access content of CKEditor on `ng-click`. When I see the source in CKEditor after adding the image, it does show me the `img` element added. Here is my Directive for CKEditor:

```
'use strict';

define(['angular'], function(angular) {

var Directives = angular.module('Directives', []);

Directives.directive('ckEditor', [function() {
        return {
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

                var ck = CKEDITOR.replace('lanEditor',{extraAllowedContent: 'img[alt,!src]{width,height}'});

                ck.on('pasteState', function() {
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                    });
                });

                ngModel.$render = function(value) {
                    ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
});
```

Below image shows source after adding image:

[image]

I have already tried `$compileProvider` - `imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist` but it is not working. I am not able to figure out if AngularJS or CKEditor is causing sanitization of `img` tags.

Comment: you sure it's not a path problem to the image?

Comment: @charlietfl No it is not path problem i guess. I tried to have a look at value passed by ckEditor using alert(JSON.stringify($scope.ckEditor.value)); It shows every element I have typed in except "img" tag shown in above image.